# Make grid lines bold that correspond to specific values in scatterplot3d

Tags: r, scatter-plot, cran

For the following 3d scatterplot,

```
require(scatterplot3d)
x <- c(1,4,3,6,2,5)
y <- c(2,2,4,3,5,9)
z <- c(1,3,5,9,2,2)
s <- scatterplot3d(x,y,z)
```

I want to emphasize (i.e. make bold) each grid line that corresponds to the value 4 on the x, y and z axes.

How might I go about doing so?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it doesn't look like there is a super straight forward way to do this in the scatter plot command itself, but you can find positions after you make the plot and draw on top.

For example

```
s <- scatterplot3d(x,y,z)
with(s$xyz.convert(c(4,4),c(2,9),c(0,0)), lines(x, y, lwd=2))
with(s$xyz.convert(c(1,6),c(4,4),c(0,0)), lines(x, y, lwd=2))
```

Here we darken the gridlines on the bottom for x=4 and y=4. Not sure where you were picturing the line for z=4.

[image: 3d scatter plot with highlighted grid marks]

Comment: Wonderful - thank you, that works well.  I am new to scatterplot 3d and still a novice with R, so your insight is much appreciated.

In thinking again about the z axis, I think a plane at z=4 and parallel to the base of the graph, rather than a line, would be most appropriate. Do you know how I would be able to do that?

Comment: How about adding the line `s$plane3d(4,0,0, lty=0, lty.box=1, lwd=2)`. See the "Value" section of `?scatterplot3d` for more info about the `xyz.convert` and `plane3d` functions (as well as others) provided by the object returned from `scatterplot3d`